# Information to be included in brochure about new undergraduate programme for admissions committees

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a student from a new undergraduate programme with only one batch of graduates. The administration is planning to create and send an official brochure/document with information about the programme to admissions committees of graduate programmes (mainly in the United States) where students may apply.

What information would about the programme would be relevant to these committees to get a better idea about what our programme is and our standards? Would it be useful, for example, to include information on textbooks followed for various courses?

Answer (score 1):

Look at how similar programs describe themselves publicly (web pages, ...), that should give a pretty clear idea. Perhaps ask around several of the interesting schools to see what they'd want to know about the program applicants went through.

If there is some suggestion of curriculum in your area (like e.g. the IEEE/ACM proposals for computer science and related fields), it would be useful to mention your program adheres to them, and perhaps highlight differences and rationale for them.

An overview of the faculty and their curricula, a general look at the school as a whole (what makes it stand out, is it research or teaching oriented, number of students, ...) is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Just from my experience as an undergrad taking graduate classes for electives

(I hear professors talk about their expectations very often)

- Mathematics/Logical Reasoning: You haven't said the programs but even things like economics need a strong math background, and more people need logic
- Student Research: Even if it's just helping gather data for a researcher (you do have those right?)
- GRE Scores: I never hear about these from professors, which tells me that the people in grad programs are acceptable
- General Aptitude: Goes along with GRE scores, some way to compare on a national scale to ensure students have learned something
- Faculty Achievements: IMO less important than most people make it out to be, but if a faculty member has earned recognition then for
  sure put it on the website (any good admissions officer won't just
  look at your brochure). Don't go too far with this, but showing that
  students have been taught by able teachers is important

Textbooks specifically (in my non-professional opinion) make it look like you're trying to fill up space. I've had professors who are very adamant about certain things tell me they've looked in every textbook to find a piece of information (I believe them, that's game theory professors for you). I think most professors with office phones have gotten calls from textbook reps. Most of them do probably know all the textbooks in their given field because of this. But who knows the connotation that professor associated with that book. It could also just be a department teaching style difference, either way I don't see this as always being a positive thing to add to a brochure.

---

In case you're curious my searched every textbook for how books modeled Deadweight Loss in a market characterized by monopolistic competition; the struggle comes from some textbooks incorrectly showing that the marginal cost curve is flat if the market were in perfect competition, when often times natural monopolies are actually more efficient due to economies of scale, think electric power generation, lets just make a large plant rather than many small ones.

He found that most either incorrectly assume a horizontal marginal cost curve, or completely ignore the topic to avoid the issue.

Sorry for the aside, if you want more information from an informed student's perspective just let me know!